# How to store location data to Asyncstorage when onpress is active

Tags: javascript, react-native

so basically I am thinking to store the location data into asyncstorage whenever the onpress button is active. I already go through to the asyncstorage documentation however I still stuck and still need some hint and more example to do the coding.

can someone help me?

```
export default class index extends Component {
  findCoordinates = () => {
    Geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
      (position) => {
        const location = JSON.stringify(position);
        this.setState({ location });
      },
      (error) => Alert.alert(error.message),
      {
        enableHighAccuracy: true,
        timeout: 20000,
        maximumAge: 1000,
        forceRequestLocation: true,
      }
    );
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <Container>
        <ScrollView>
          <View style={styles.top}></View>
          <Card
            containerStyle={{
              borderRadius: 10,
              marginTop: -30,
            }}
          >
            <View>
              <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.findCoordinates}>
                <Text>Find My Coords?</Text>
                <Text>Location: {this.state.location}</Text>
              </TouchableOpacity>
            </View>
          </Card>
        </ScrollView>
      </Container>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that you have already imported the following:

```
import {AsyncStorage} from 'react-native';
```

Please add the following codes after you click the button :

```
AsyncStorage.setItem('storedlocation', this.state.location);
```

next time, if you want to get the asyncstorage value, say into the state of "retrievedlocation", please use the following codes:

```
  getstoredlocationFunction = () => {

    AsyncStorage.getItem('storedlocation').then(

      value2 =>

        this.setState({ retrievedlocation: value2 })

    );

  };
```

Have a nice day.